# sendRedirect not redirecting

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to create a Java controller servlet to log users out of the session. 
I know there's 2 methods, one by using sendRedirect and the other is RequestDispatcher. In my case, I want to send them to a page outside of the domain, which (to my limited Java knowledge) requires me to use sendRedirect.

However, I'm getting an Error 302 and the page does not get redirected. I have tried a tutorial version and it works, but when I implement it within my Servlet, it returns me the error and does not redirect.

I hope someone could point me in the right direction.

The code I'm using is as below. I'm using the netbeans template:

---

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalidated");

            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
            return;
            /*
            String url = "/logout.jsp";

            ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher(url);
            rd.include(request, response);

             */
        }
        /* TODO output your page here
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet LogOut</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet LogOut at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
         */
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I'm calling the servlet via a `<a href>` tag. Servlet name is LogOut.java.

```
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
            <a href="LogOut" data-theme="i">Log Out</a>
        </div>
```

The doGet and doPost calls the processRequest.

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

Comment: `302` isn't an error; it's a status code telling the browser to redirect.

Comment: Hi skaffman, thanks for the quick reply. I'm not sure myself, as it's based on googling what I found via firebug. But what is preventing the browser from redirecting? Could it be due to my use of jQueryMobile in the jsp pages?

Answer (score 0):

Standard redirection of the response is a reference within your application.
To solve this I've created a simple HTML page with meta data refresh to the external page:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp 
Example:
`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2; URL=http://www.google.be;">`

Make sure to a simple hyperlink to access the external page should the automatic forwarding fail.

Once tested, the response from the Servlet was redirected to my own forwarding page and voila...

Comment: Hi Jan, does that mean there's no way to redirect from the servlet immediately without the use of an extra HTML page? But when I was following a tutorial, it worked fine. I'm not sure why this occurs only after I tried to implement it within my own servlet.

Comment: `response.sendRedirect` is the correct way and it should work.I doubt there might be some other code in `doPost()` or `doGet()` which causing the problem.
Provide the code from you are calling `processRequest`.

Comment: Hi Hardik, I have added the information requested to the post. Hope to hear from you soon.